# OpenSSL e ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, openssl, revisão-de-código

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação interna, porém em um certo modulo vou precisar trafegar um certo dado sensivel.

A priori pensei em usar SSL, porém devido a limitações (**não técnicas**) não poderei fazê-lo, então pensei em usar OpenSSL.

Até consegui fazer funcionar usando a implementação abaixo, porém não sei se a mesma está implementada da forma correta, então gostaria que alguém a revisasse.

**Model**

```
public class SecurityModel
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string PublicKey { get; set; }
}

public class EncryptedModel
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string Encrypted { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<SecurityModel> GeneratePublicKey()
{
    var model = new SecurityModel();
    using (var generator = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024))
    {
        try
        {
            var token = Convert.ToBase64String(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray());
            var keys = generator.ExportParameters(true);
            var pemString = generator.GetPublicKeyAsPemString();

            MemoryCache.Default.Add(token, keys, new CacheItemPolicy
            {
                AbsoluteExpiration = ObjectCache.InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration,
                SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                Priority = CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable
            });

            model.Token = token;
            model.PublicKey = pemString;
        }
        finally
        {
            generator.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        }
    }
    return model;
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<bool> ReadSensitiveData(EncryptedModel model)
{
    using (var generator = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024))
    {
        try
        {
            var keys = (RSAParameters)MemoryCache.Default.Get(model.Token);
            generator.ImportParameters(keys);

            var binary = Convert.FromBase64String(model.Encrypted);
            var decrypted = generator.Decrypt(binary, false);
            var sensitive = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);

            return sensitive == "Sensitive Data";
        }
        finally
        {
            generator.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

A extensão `RSAUtils.GetPublicKeyAsPemString(this RSACryptoServiceProvider csp)` basicamente devolve a chave publica no formato esperado no JavaScript. Algo semelhante à:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDlOJu6TyygqxfWT7eLtGDwajtN
FOb9I5XRb6khyfD1Yt3YiCgQWMNW649887VGJiGr/L5i2osbl8C9+WJTeucF+S76
xFxdU6jE0NQ+Z+zEdhUTooNRaY5nZiu5PgDB0ED/ZKBUSLKL7eibMxZtMlUDHjm4
gwQco1KRMDSmXSMkDwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Agora segue os meus scripts:

**Depedências**

[`A Javascript library to perform OpenSSL RSA Encryption, Decryption, and Key Generation`](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt)

**Scripts**

```
var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
var token = "";
var generatePublicKey = function () {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', '/api/Security/', true);
    httpRequest.responseType = "json";
    httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
            token = httpRequest.response.Token;
            encrypt.setPublicKey(httpRequest.response.PublicKey);
            sendSensitiveData();
        }
    });
    httpRequest.send();
}

var sendSensitiveData = function () {
    var sensitive = "Sensitive Data";
    var encrypted = encrypt.encrypt(sensitive);

    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('POST', '/api/Security/', true);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(httpRequest);
        }
    });
    httpRequest.send(JSON.stringify({ Token: token, Encrypted: encrypted }));
}

generatePublicKey();
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: @DenerCavalho não era bem um problema, o algoritmo acima está funcionando, a minha dúvida era se estava bem implementado ou se havia uma forma melhor de fazê-lo.

Comment: @TobyMosque você ainda tem dúvida sobre a implementação?

Comment: @durtto, a implementação acima está funcionando, mas ainda acho que poderia melhorar, se você tiver algo à acrescentar, eu serei muito grato.

Answer (score 2):

Cara, a solução não é 100% seguro, mas já tem algumas proteções, o ideal é convencer o uso do SSL. (é possível conseguir certificados válidos por preços bem acessíveis).

Mas sobre o seu caso, em um ataque de sniffer creio que esteja protegido, mas o ataque for mais elaborado, não... Faça um teste, ative o Fiddler para descriptografar SSL, mas sem instalar o certificado. Tipo, ir até o passo três do link abaixo: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/FirefoxHTTPS

Ao acessar qualquer site https, os navegadores modernos irão abrir uma página avisando que há algo errado com certificado, creio que no seu site isso não vai ocorrer (se fizer o teste nos passe o que aconteceu), a princípio imagino que os dados poderão está criptografados no Fiddler, mas se não houve alerta, significa que um programa qualquer poderia estar no lugar do Fiddler alternado os dados de envios e de recebimento, fazendo uma ponte entre o cliente e o servidor, e dessa forma, obtendo os dados criptografados. É verdade que é um ataque mais complexo, mas estará exposto, dependendo da criticidade dos dados, não me arriscaria.