# C# Encriptação de ficheiros

Tags: c#, criptografia

Desejo enviar ficheiros para amigos mas quero ter a certeza de ninguém pode ver o seu conteúdo.

**Gostaria de um exemplo para realizar a encriptação dos ficheiros em C#.**

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/307010 veja se esse exemplo lhe ajuda

Comment: Tem esse outro exemplo também http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131443/5846

Comment: Você conseguiu achar a resposta?

Answer (score 1):

Existem muitas soluções para isso que você quer fazer, como a pergunta está muito vaga, vou passar apenas a parte de criptografia. Umas das mais simples é usar criptografia simétrica, onde se usa a mesma chave para criptografar e descriptografar, a desvantagem dessa solução é que você deve compartilhar essa chave com seus amigos de forma antecipada. Segue um tutorial que achei em português.

http://devbrasil.net/profiles/blogs/criptografia-em-c-aes

Mas você pode fazer algo até mais simples, fazendo apenas uma compactação via zip com password usando bibliotecas como: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/